# Failed to Parse JSON in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to parse a Json. I have successfully passed the Json onto string, but I can't convert it onto JObject. Here is my attempt code:

```
private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   string jsonStr = e.Result;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonStr))
   {
      JObject objects = JObject.Parse(jsonStr); // this is when the error came at the first time. It says: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occured in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code.
      JArray a = (JArray)objects[""];
      IList<Feeds.Topic> listFeeds = a.ToObject<IList<Feeds.Topic>>();
      this.DataContext = listFeeds;
   }
}
```

And here is the source of JSON: http://apibiru.herokuapp.com/v0.1/feeds/1?auth_token=64d362d2e483e8023c46595f83ca8d9555ff6d7cc700a2474fbdbd341c43c1fb

I appreciate your help if you can help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(jsonStr);
```

I tried to parse your json using the Class that got from http://json2csharp.com/. I think you have to parse it directly

```
List<RootObject> yourObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonStr);
```

Since you need Json Object you can try the first option

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(jsonStr);
```

Don't try to parse into a JObject first as your data is an array as it starts with [ and ends with ].